# Installing J2EE into existing eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have Eclipse Galileo (Version: 3.5.2), which I use to develop Jave SE applications. I want to learn Java EE. How do I incorporate Java EE? Or do I need to install a Java EE specific Eclipse IDE?

Follow Up:

Thanks a great deal for answering!
There are a lot of names in the list that shows up in Eclipse. E.g. WTP 3.1.1, WTP 3.1.2, Patches, WTP Test 3.1.1, WTP Test 3.1.2. Which ones do I download?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Step 1
Go to Help `--->` Install New Software...

Step 2
Try to find "http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates" under work with drop down. If you find then select and install all the available updates.

If you can not find then click on Add -> Add Repository.
Name: Eclipse Webtools
Location: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates
Select all available updates and Install them.

Visit http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/ for more details.

Comment: There are a lot of names of the list. E.g. WTP 3.1.1, WTP 3.1.2, Patches, WTP Test 3.1.1, WTP Test 3.1.2. Which ones Do I use?

Comment: Eclipse Indigo (3.7) is the most latest one. Get updates for Indigo (3.7). You should get WTP 3.3 here is more details http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.3.0/index.php

Comment: What if you have Juno version? I've got Juno j2se and I want to update to juno j2ee.

Comment: Didn't worked for me, its showing 

'Installing Software' has encountered a problem.
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

Answer (score 37):

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/ - This is an old URL and doesn't work any more.
If you want to install WTP (i.e. J2EE plugins) use the following URLs depending upon the version of the eclipse you are using:

- For Photon (Eclipse 4.8) and WTP 3.10 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/
- For Oxygen (Eclipse 4.7) and WTP 3.9 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/
- For Neon (Eclipse 4.6) and WTP 3.8 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/
- For Luna (Eclipse 4.4) and WTP 3.6 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/
- For Kepler (Eclipse 4.3) and WTP 3.5 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/
- For Juno (Eclipse 3.8/4.2) and WTP 3.4- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/
- For Indigo (Eclipse 3.7/4.1) and WTP 3.3- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
- For Helios (Eclipse 3.6) and WTP 3.2 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/

More information can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F).

Comment: There's also information what makes up a specific Eclipse package in the Eclipse downloads area. The current "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" info is here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2 (very useful for installing via P2 director)

Answer (score 6):

For Mars (Eclipse 4.5) and WTP 3.7 use this link.
http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/mars/

1. In Eclipse select Help - Install New Software.
2. In the "Work with:" text box place the above link.
3. Press Enter.
4. Select the WTP version you need (3.7.0 or 3.7.1 as of today) & follow the prompts.

Comment: Didn't worked for me, its showing 

'Installing Software' has encountered a problem.
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

Answer (score 4):

Go to Help -> Install new softwares-> add -> paste this link in location box http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna/ 
install all new versions..

Answer (score 2):

You could install Web Tool Platform on top of your current installation to help you learn about Java EE. Download the [Web Tools Platform](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/) by using Eclipse Software Update (Instruction at http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/). It has features to get you going with learning Java EE. You could learn more about Web Tools Platform at http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse Mars the following worked

1. In Eclipse select Help - Install New Software.
2. Search for "EE". Got two hits and it what obvious which to use.
3. Let IDE restart.