#  How do I make Eclipse recognize the Java compiler (1.6) and projects facet (1.6) do, in fact, match in GAE project?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm using Eclipse version 4.2, I have the GWT plugin installed, and created a new Web Application Project and enabled GAE and GWT. I'm getting an error stating "Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet." I have the compiler level set to 1.6. My version of eclipse does not seem to have an option to change the facet version in the UI (i.e. select project properties, no option on left for facets...), so after some searching I found that the org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file could be edited (under my project/.settings/ folder), so I went in and changed "version" to "1.6" Rebuilt the project, closed and reopened eclipse a billion times, and tried changing every setting and searching for every instance of "1.7" in the project I could to ensure Java 1.6 is being used for everything, yet I still get an error stating the compiler level and installed Java project facet do not match. I have searched and searched, and most posts tend to recommend going to project, properties and selecting project facets on the left. This DOES NOT APPEAR, and I have changed the file in .settings to indicate 1.6 (i've closed and reopened several times to confirm this has saved, and rebuilt the project to ensure it knows this has been changed). Help, please! Oh, and I'm using Windows 7.

Java 6 (JDK 1.6) is installed on my system.

Comment: What kind of questions can I ask here?

...We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
***--software tools commonly used by programmers--***
practical, ***answerable problems*** that are unique to the programming profession
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: I guess the question is "how do I make Eclipse recognize the Java compiler (1.6) and projects facet (1.6) do, in fact, match?" I'll update the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install webtools for eclipse [Installing J2EE into existing eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170694/installing-j2ee-into-existing-eclipse-ide)

Now you ll have project facets in your project properties

Check that you have the right version of java and it will build

Comment: There seem to be a large amount of resources not included in the Classic version of Eclipse that are required for webtools. I'm less worried about being able to update facets via the Eclipse UI and more concerned with why eclipse won't allow me to compile or test the project because it doesn't recognize that both the java compile level and the project facets version are set to 1.6...

Comment: i had the **exact** same problem. I added the facet UI and that solved my problem. Which happens to be the same as yours. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, @jidma. I cannot seem to get this to work, eclipse gives me one heck of a list of missing dependencies. I found I am able to upload the project to App Engine, so I'm gonna stick with that for testing for now (although it's not ideal, of course) until I can figure out what I need to do to get eclipse working. I've started downloading the Java EE version of eclipse to run alongside my Classic version (Classic for android, and EE for web projects), and hopefully that will work. Thanks again!

Comment: @theBakedBaker welcome man, i hope you'll fix your problem soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have only the java JDK 1.7 installed on your system and need to install the JDK 1.6

**Appengine is only compatible with java SDK 1.6**. You can download it [here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6u35-downloads-1836443.html)

Comment: Sorry, I should have included this. I only have java 6 installed on my system (JDK 1.6).