# How to install Java EE in Eclipse without repositories

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am working on eclipse and I need Java EE. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170694/installing-j2ee-into-existing-eclipse-ide), but the problem is that when installing it stops because I don't have proxy permission.

So the question is where can I install Java EE without using `Eclipse` -> `Help` -> `Install New Software` -> `URL repositories` ?

Comment: Lazy I know but could you not just download the J2EE Version of Eclipse rather than upgrading your current install?

Comment: Because I already have one with Java SE.

Comment: What is the most simple ?
Build a Eclipse IDE yourself or download one already packaged ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should set proxy in eclipse, Window > Preferences > General > Network connection.